# Is COVID pronounced as /ˌkəʊ vid/?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

I've tested it in [Microsoft Bing Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator?mkt=zh-CN) (pronounced it as /ˌkəʊ vid/, the result is unstable (sometimes it shows correctly and sometimes not. - How to use the Translator? - Type abc into the left textbox and the icon of a mic will show up; click the mic and speak). Here's [How to Pronounce COVID](https://www.howtopronounce.com/covid). But I need phonetic symbles to be spelt out.

> Bill Gates tweeted
> COVID-19 has cost lives, sickened millions, and thrust the global economy into a devastating recession. But hope is on the horizon:

Comment: Like all pronunciation, it depends on who is speaking.  Here in Scotland, I mainly hear /kɒvɪd/ or /kəʊvɪd/ or /kəʊvəd/, but it's likely that other variants exist.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit on the full English Language stack.  [Related.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/528487/107198)

Comment: @TobySpeight "but it's likely that other variants exist" I see what you did there

Comment: The first pronunciation on the howtopronounce site sounds really weird. That presumably is because it is being said by a non English speaker.  Of course COVID19 does not restrict itself by language barriers so perhaps you are asking an impossible question. **Question:** Whose pronunciation do you want? American? British? French? etc. etc.

Comment: Do you know IPA well? Do you want a spelling for a particular country or do you want a broad transcription that's fairly dialect-neutral? The long O phoneme is pronounced /əʊ/ in at least part of England, and /oʊ/ in most of the U.S. and Canada.

Comment: @ chasly - supports Monica:  I want to know its sound in American English - International Version.

Comment: On 'howtopronounce' only versions 3 & 4 are anything like English pronunciation, (though idk if they change position based on votes. I upvoted the two good ones & dv'd the others)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no rule agreed to yet because it's the combination of acronym and brand new. But most of people on a TV or Radio pronounce it as /koʊvɪd/. It's because of "O" in the word.

Comment: And *who* makes those rules?

Comment: It's a phenomenon that we are just going through. It remains to be seen.

Comment: I mean who makes the rules about pronunciation? You say *'there's no rule agreed to yet..'*, but then you say *'it's because of the "O"'*.... both the statements are contradictory.

Comment: alphabet O makes /oʊ/ that's why we can hear people say /koʊ/ and there's no rule agreed to yet. After this disaster is over, the word may appear in a dictionary with pronunciation symbol; the lexicographers will decide which symbol is appropriate considering phenomenon and spelling.

Comment: It's not because the 'alphabet O makes /oʊ/'. Alphabets don't make sounds, they're just the  **written** counterparts of sounds. /// It's pronounced /əʊ/ (/oʊ/) because the first syllable is open (see my answer). Syllables are a unit of spoken language and have nothing to do with spelling/alphabets.

Comment: @Void But how do you decide if a syllable is open or closed? The *written* syllables seem to not make sounds neither.

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira: It's frustratingly complex. (For starters, read Maximal Onset Principle.)

Comment: There are no rules. Only guidelines based on precedent.

Comment: It's not an acronym, it's a shortening of COronaVIrus Disease.

Comment: @OrangeDog - My definition of acronym would include that. Like telco or comicon.

Comment: @Void: In most cases you'd be right that the spelling doesn't decide the pronunciation, but with acronyms the pronunciation really *is* derived from the spelling, because the word is coined by taking written letters from the starts of written words, and assembling them. (The resulting pronunciation often uses very different sounds from the original words; for example, the "a" and "s" of "laser" are pronounced nothing like the "a" and "s" of "amplification" and "stimulated".)

Comment: @OrangeDog I keep trying to convince people it should therefore be pronounced to rhyme with *provide*…

Answer (score 13):

/ˈkoʊvɪd/  Primary stress on first syllable. "co" as in "cove" not as in "coffee" vid as in "video", not as "vine" (nor "virus".)

This should now be in online dictionaries, even if not in paper ones.

Answer (score 6):

I would transcribe it /'koʊ vɪd/, being a Midwest Am.E speaker, but the exact character of the first vowel is highly dependent on dialect. For example, Southern Am.E would exaggerate the dipthong; Scottish would have no or almost no dipthong; and the initial /o/ may sound more like an /ə/ in some accents.

Comment: Thank you guys. That worked.   Could you transcribe Pfizer and Moderna, two companies who developed COVID vaccines?   Pfizer:  /fai.tsər/? Moderna: /ˈmɒd.ənə/?

Comment: @NewPlanet: I've heard 'Pfizer' pronounced /ˈfaɪ.zə/. 'Moderna' is stressed on the second syllable.

Comment: Could Microsoft Translator (see the OP) recognize your voice when you read Pfizer aloud?

Comment: Pfizer rhymes with [Tizer](https://www.agbarr.co.uk/our-brands/tizer/) no 'p' & no 'ts'. It's American not German. Moderna, as Void said, like cod **learn**er.

Comment: Moderna:  /mɒdˈə:.nə/?

Comment: I don't read phonetics, sorry. Mod as in 'fashionable youth from the 60's with a motor scooter'. Earner like someone who is paid to do a job, or a beginner driver (learner) without the L.. Emphasis on 'earn'.

Comment: @NewPlanet: /məˈdɜːnə/

Comment: @Void I think whether "Pfizer" is pronounced with the "r" sound at the end depends on whether or not you speak a rhotic or non-rhotic dialect of English.

Comment: @nick012000: Of course! I'm a speaker of a non-rhotic accent, so I wrote the non-rhotic version

Answer (score 1):

The "vid" bit never seems to be in dispute; it's like the "vid" of "video".

The "co" bit, I hear pronounced like "co" from "cone" about two thirds of the time, and "co" from "coffee" the rest of the time. Though the former seems to be winning, the latter makes more sense, given that it's taken from "corona".

Comment: This leads me to ask, how are you pronouncing "corona"?  I hear the first 'o' in that pronounced like "cup" most often, and "cone" the rest of the time.  Never like "coffee" though.

Comment: I have not heard one person say: kawvid, like coffee.

Comment: @Lambie depends how you say "coffee". Trying to describe pronunciation without IPA or at least a reference accent is useless.

Comment: @OrangeDog Nope, I am using what the poster said. co like coffee as opposed to co like cone. His posting of the sounds in coffee and cone. Not mine.

Comment: @Lambie yes I know. I am criticising both of you.

Comment: @OrangeDog When written as a contrast to another word, it makes sense, because it removes the pronunciation that's similar to cone out of possibility

Comment: "The "vid" bit never seems to be in dispute; it's like the "vid" of "video"." - um, I have never heard anyone pronounce it like that. It's always pronounced with a shwa, as far as I can tell, like the last syllable of "livid".

Comment: @SteveBennett - what are you perceiving as the difference between the vid in video & livid? To me they are identical. I've never heard anyone pronounce it cove-èd or cov-əd, always with a distinct i.  The co as in cone I'm with, but I'd bet it's because of association with words like co-operative, co-educational & because to pronounce it covvid like coffee or constant (identical in my accent, N.BrE, no cawfee where I live;), you'd want to see two v's.

Comment: @SteveBennett the "vid" in "video" and "livid" I've always heard pronounced the same (and I've lived in a variety of parts of the UK and Australia) apart from the fact that in both words the first syllable is stressed.

Comment: That would really surprise me if there are many native Australian speakers not reducing a final syllable to a shwa like that. (Should have mentioned, I'm Australian living in Melbourne.)

Comment: An example of the Australian schwa pronunciation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avhcZTY7t94

Comment: @SteveBennett - Aussie never even occurred to me, sorry. I was all Northern hemisphere ;) Of course, in that case covid will be like David, or should I spell it Diyvud :P